# If Lucifer was top perfect creature, how could he fall? [Catholicism]

Tags: catholicism, sin, creation, satan, free-will

Since God's creation is good/perfect, how could a creature as good/perfect as a top angel actually fall, according to Catholicism? What is the mechanism of corruption that can corrupt a perfect being? Since God is incorruptible, He is then still the absolute perfect, while any other creature with free will cannot be absolutely perfect. But then, what is the guarantee that humans or saint angels will not fall again, being already in heaven?

Comment: It is the beatific vision that guarantees our will fixed in God's will. It seems the angels didn't have it prior to their fall and their will was not fixed in God's. Something like you wouldn't trade a sin for a penny if you just won a lottery with mega-millions.

Comment: Being a top angel might actually make it easier to sin by thinking "I'm practically as great as God."

Comment: @AndreasBlass But he knew he wasn't as great as God, as no one can ever be.

Comment: Yes, he's smart enough to know that. But one who knows he's not as great as God yet still thinks he's anywhere near comparable to God still sins by pride.

Comment: It appears as though angels cannot create, while God can.

Answer (score 1):

Angels, incorporeal intellectual beings, cannot become less perfectly angelic (unlike humans, who can become more or less human); also, [every angel is its own species](https://isidore.co/aquinas/summa/FP/FP050.html#FPQ50A4THEP1). However, [there can still be "evil of fault" (*malum culpæ*) in angels](https://isidore.co/aquinas/summa/FP/FP063.html#FPQ63A1THEP1), not in their intellects but in their wills. [Angels have freewill.](https://isidore.co/aquinas/summa/FP/FP059.html#FPQ59A3THEP1)

Comment: Do you mean that angels can either be completely good or completely evil, and nothing in-between?

Comment: @sequence All angels are naturally good; even [demons (fallen angels) are not naturally evil](https://isidore.co/aquinas/summa/FP/FP063.html#FPQ63A4THEP1).

Comment: Yes but if I understood your answer post correctly, humans can be less human, but angels cannot be less angelic. Does this mean that fallen angels are necessarily absolutely evil?

Comment: @sequence Angels cannot become less angelic. By nature, all angels (even fallen angels) are good. Fallen angels' wills make them do evil.

Comment: Isn't it true that people also apply their own will in order to do evil? @Geremia

Comment: @sequence Yes. And when humans do evil they become less human.